# need service suggetsion for Azure API monitoring

Tags: azure

Im using a 3rd party API (IPStack) in my web application. I need a service in Azure   to monitor the API twice a day to check its status if it is responding. Please suggest the best service to use for the same

Comment: I suggest you can take a look at [url ping test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability#setup) in application insights. But it test every 5 or 10 or 15 minutes, cannot configure to twice a day.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: Nope Ivan, im planning create a service runs daily 3 times

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can take a look at u[rl ping test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability#setup) in application insights. But it test every 5 or 10 or 15 minutes and not twice a day.

Just put the url and some other configuration.

**If you just use application insights for creating url ping test, it's free.**

[image]